# fopen(C:\wamp64\www\jarian\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied Windows 10 Wamp

Tags: php, windows, wamp

i am using laravel excel to import some excel files to database . when i insert the file i get this error :

```
fopen(C:\wamp64\www\jarian\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

it's 2 days that i am searching all forums and documentations about permissions and yet i got no success. my files are not read-only my user have admin access and like below :

[image]

you can see that the folder is not read-only but yet i get this error :
[image]

dont think its a code error but i place my code any way :

```
 public function newsImportStore(Request $request)
    {

        Excel::import(new NewsImport(), $request->file('file'));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `$request->file('file')` You do have a form set up to upload a file?

Comment: It's not necessarily about read-only, it's about whether the IIS account (or whatever account you're running the site as) has permissions to read from that folder/file. Go to the Security tab for the file/folder in question and check

Comment: @ADyson i have granted the premission to user to have full access to that folder

Comment: @Farshad so then why did you show us a totally different, irrelevant screenshot which you claim shows us that you gave "admin access"? That suggested to me that you didn't actually understand what the correct process is to grant such access. The screenshot you've shown does not prove to us that you've given the correct permissions.

Comment: @ADyson i did not understand why  u got angry but i attached the screen shot from permissions

Comment: I'm not angry at all, you misunderstand. I'm just baffled why you would show a screenshot of something irrelevant and then claim it represents something else. (Although I could be angry for wasting the time of people trying to help you, I'm more just confused).

Comment: Anyway so... I see you've given yourself full permission, but your website doesn't necessarily run under your own account. Unless you've specifically configured IIS to do that, it won't.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for trying to help in the first but no one wants to waste no ones time here  :) i wanted to show the readyonly state on first screen shot

Comment: @ADyson i am using wamp thats i think where dont have the premission

Comment: Like I said, the read only status is completely irrelevant. So...you're serving the site through Apache instead of IIS? I see. You need to check what account the Apache service runs as, then

Comment: ok thanks @ADyson for help just know that ready only state is the first problem on wamp when getting to these issues if u search u find out :) thanks for you answers